# Javascript get nearby Bluetooth devices Mac Address

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth, progressive-web-apps

I need my web project to get nearby Bluetooth devices Mac Address.
I use this code:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(acceptAllDevices)
.then(device => {
console.log(device)
console.log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
console.log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
console.log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
})
.catch(error => {
console.log('Argh! ' + error);
});
```

When I run this function get this tab: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnzvA.png)

For unsupported devices, the Bluetooth Mac Address is displayed. But its name property will be null.

However, for recognized devices, it prints the name option.
Can I filter the Mac address from the name option?

There may be other ways to query Mac address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available filters for Web Bluetooth are "Services", "Name", "Name prefix", and "Manufacturer data" as described at https://web.dev/bluetooth/#request.

You can try some combination at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html and https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/manufacturer-data-filter.html

Regarding the MAC address, it depends on Bluetooth devices. Some devices broadcast either an ephemeral one for privacy, a "static" one, a name which is used for "device.name" when there's one instead of the MAC address.

Which device are you trying to access? Check out `about:bluetooth-internals#devices` and try to identify one thing that makes it unique.